# Spamassassin filter systematically produces negative (ham) scores for spam messages

Tags: email, postfix, spam, dovecot, spamassassin

I have problem with lots of spam.
My server setup is VPS with CentOS 6.5 and Dovecot+Postfix+Spamassassin.

Here is source of one of the messages:

```
Return-Path: <nancy_mitchell@tagbook.co.nz>
X-Spam-Checker-Version: SpamAssassin 3.3.1 (2010-03-16) on xxxxxx.xx
X-Spam-Level: 
X-Spam-Status: No, score=-0.5 required=3.0 tests=HTML_MESSAGE,
    HTML_MIME_NO_HTML_TAG,MIME_HTML_ONLY,RP_MATCHES_RCVD,URIBL_BLOCKED
    autolearn=ham version=3.3.1
Delivered-To: mail@xxxxxx.xx
Received: by mx.xxxxxx.xx (Postfix, from userid 5001)
    id 584194399E; Sun, 14 Sep 2014 04:34:03 +0200 (CEST)
Received: from tagbook.co.nz (tagbook.co.nz [119.47.112.73])
    by mx.xxxxxx.xx (Postfix) with ESMTP id 6089C43119
    for <mail@xxxxxx.xx>; Sun, 14 Sep 2014 04:33:59 +0200 (CEST)
Date: Sun, 14 Sep 2014 14:33:56 +1200
From: "Nancy Mitchell" <nancy_mitchell@tagbook.co.nz>
Reply-To:"Nancy Mitchell" <nancy_mitchell@tagbook.co.nz>
Message-ID: <59a5f3f-c3c7f-b8@tagbook.co.nz>
To: mail@xxxxxx.xx
Subject: RE:  Lol adooya
X-Priority: 3 (Normal)
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/html; charset="iso-8859-1"
Content-Transfer-Encoding: 8bit


<h2><a href="http://www.dirtymath.co.kr/data/question/g0702/login.html?ZGpwQmRqcGxndixndw==">adooya</a></h2>
<div> The  artifact  was instantly forgotten-as I hoped, although  it  took
</div>
```

As you can see, this message only got spam score -0.5.
Anybody got any idea, what to do with this? It's pretty annoying.

Comment: Do you use bulk detectors (razor/pyzor/dcc) as Aragon0 suggested?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Turning off a few spamassassin tests

According to my SA configuration from the above tests only `RP_MATCHES_RCVD` yields negative score (ham indicator). `RP_MATCHES_RCVD` scores between -1.5 and -0.5 (local/network, with bayes/without bayes).

You may consider turning the test off as described in `man Mail::SpamAssassin::Conf`.

~/.spamassassin/user_prefs

```
score RP_MATCHES_RCVD 0
```

Comment: I did this, and it worked better. I combined it with solution from @Aragon0 and it works like a charm now. Thanks

Answer (score 3):

Install DCC, Pyzor and Razor2. That improves detection significantly. If you still get spam, write some meta-rules (for example DCC + Blacklist = +2 score). I block more than 300 spams per week with an accuracy beyond 99% with that method.

Comment: Thank you, I installed Pyzor and Razor. The detection is much better now.